# xtlogit: panel data transformation's recast to double makes model incomputable (STATA)

Tags: data-transformation, maximum-likelihood, stata, panel-data, convergence

I am experiencing a very peculiar problem in STATA. I have a panel dataset with 8000 groups and 4 million observations. I want to run a fixed effects panel binary logistic regression (xtlogit).

As you can read in [my original question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54750/binary-panel-logistic-regression-xtlogit-fixed-effects-is-not-converging-in-st), STATA's maximization algorithm cannot compute a solution when using `xtlogit`. I have reduced this problem to occurring when transforming the data to panel data, because:

1. running `logit depvar indepvars` works just fine
2. `logit depvar indepvars` does not maximize when first running `xtdata indepvars, fe clear`

Therefore `xtdata` does something that causes the maximizer to fail. It turns out that when I run `xtdata indepvars, fe clear nodouble` it does compute. This means that stata's panel function cause the data to be recast to the `double` format (from `float`), and this increased precision causes the maximization process to fail.

However, I cannot use `logit` after `xtdata .., nodouble` because it is not the same as running `xtlogit` (`xtdata` is meant for OLS). Therefore  I need to run `xtlogit`, but it does not seem to have a `nodouble` option, causing STATA to recast the "hidden background panel" data to the `double` format with higher precision, and therefore the function fails to converge.

So, is it possible to somehow tell STATA to not recast my `float`s to `double`s when running `xtlogit`, such that the function will converge?

Is there any other solution to this increased precision issue causing the function to fail to converge?

Comment: This has been posted on Statalist too. Neither forum has rules against cross-posting to the other; nevertheless anyone tempted to reply on Cross Validated should check out the Statalist archives to avoid repeating points already made. You do not need to join or register; you can go straight to stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-04/msg00032.html to see discussion.